# Internal Microphone not working on Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen 2 (AMD)

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I'm using the Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen 2 laptop with an AMD processor. Unfortunately, the internal microphone is not available in the system settings.

In Pulseaudio volume control (pavucontrol) two microphones are available:

```
Family 17h (Models 10h1fh) HD Audio Controller Digital Microphone
Port: Digital Microphone
Family 17h (Models 10h1fh) HD Audio Controller Headphones Stereo Microphone
Port: Headphones Stereo Microphone (unplugged)
```

The headphones stereo microphone is the internal microphone. This becomes apparent by just speaking and seeing the microphone input volume increase. But only the digital microphone shows up in the Ubuntu system settings. Only some programs like [OBS](https://obsproject.com) are able to use the actual microphone when it's specifically selected.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the microphone being marked as unplugged. Which makes sense since no external microphone is plugged in the AUX jack. But this maybe causes Ubuntu to not make this microphone available.

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Linux kernel 5.8.10-050810-generic
linux-firmware 1.187.3

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on a Lenovo Ideapad 5 15, AMD ryzen 7 4800U. This is a regression, as it was working before updating my kernel to 5.8.8 (I believe I was at 5.7.8 or similar previously).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue for me by installing the newest 5.9 Linux kernel from [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/). Now, the microphone works completely fine. In the [5.9 release notes](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/CAHk-=wi-u86++np80GQvgDuARdt9xpBNho6SjHLmYgm8jibGag@mail.gmail.com/T/#u) thinkpad shows up several times but I'm unsure what is talked about specifically.

Comment: I am having the same issue on an HP ProBook 445 G7 (Ryzen 5 4500U). Mic works fine with 5.7.x and 5.9.x, but not with 5.8.x. I can't use 5.9 as there is no VirtualBox support yet (and some bluetooth issues). I might just go back to 5.7... :(