# Internal AMD Microphone not working

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, asus, microphone

I've live booted Ubuntu on my Zephyrus GA401L for the first time. My internal AMD microphone is not working in Linux, however it is working in Windows. Here are the outputs of some relevant commands:

> lspci -vv output available at https://pastebin.com/p7H9xxLf

```
$ sudo arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC289 Analog [ALC289 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: acp [acp], device 0: DMIC capture dmic-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of [Internal Microphone not working on Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen 2 (AMD)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277606/internal-microphone-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e14-gen-2-amd) as that question was resolved by a kernel update to 5.9. I'm already on 5.10

Comment: I have the same problem on an intel laptop by hp :(

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internal Microphone not working on Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen 2 (AMD)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277606/internal-microphone-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e14-gen-2-amd)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277606/internal-microphone-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e14-gen-2-amd asked before

Comment: I downloaded the latest file (i.e downloaded it today itself)ubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: quick update -> I connected a webcam having external microphone and it's working fine, but the internal mic is still not working